# How to render nested views with different query parameters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

How can I render a child view or 2 views at the same time if the parent or one of the views has a query with a parameter ?

```
export const router = createRouter({
...
routes: [
   path: '/videolist',
   component: VideoList,
    children: [
     path: '/vid',
     component: Vid
]
]
})
```

If I push just a path with no query string this works:

`this.$router.push({path: '/videolist'})`

But if I push a query parameter

`this.$router.push({path: '/videolist', query: {listid: someId}})` the url becomes something like `domainame/medialist?listId=445657` now I can no longer render the child component too.

How can I render multiple views with dynamic query strings ?

`website/view?someId=43534/anotehrView=otherId`